# How To Recursivley Diff Files With Different Names

Tags: linux, unix, diff

I have two directories that I want to compare the contents of. The structure of all the sub-directories underneath the top level directories that I want to compare is the same, but the file names are slightly different. E.g. I want to know if `/d1/foo/bar/somefile-v2.txt` is different to `/d2/foo/bar/somefile-v3.txt`.

I've found references that say it should be possible to do this using `diff`, but I can't find any documentation that tells me how to specify how `diff` maps from one file name to the other.

Comment: You have to have some kind of mappings or some logic between filenames?

Comment: It's literally the one character: -v2.txt vs -v3.txt

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you're referring to is diff's recursive option which in turn will compare all the files in a directory against another.

By reading your comments one can assume that:

1. File names are different
2. Using diff alone will not suffice.

You can just write a shell script to take care of this, but to answer your question: No, this can't be done with diff alone.

Note: you can use wildcards for the whole 1 character difference thing but it won't work recursively the way you want it to work.